# AspectJ in multiproject build with Gradle

Tags: gradle, aspectj

Dev Environment: Eclipse, Gradle plugin, AspectJ plugin, WiildFly 11
Project structure: core project and webapp project, which are two seperate projects with Gradle and AspectJ added in Eclipse
Problem: execution of Gradle war task fails

Stacktrace:

```
:core:compileAspect[ant:iajc] abort ABORT -- (RuntimeException) Problem 

processing attributes in C:\...\core\build\classes\...\AbstractClassInCore.class
Problem processing attributes in C:\...\core\build\classes\...\AbstractClassInCore.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem processing attributes in C:\...\core\build\classes\...\AbstractClassInCore.class
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureAspectJAttributesUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:387)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.<init>(BcelObjectType.java:162)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.buildBcelDelegate(BcelWorld.java:410)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:478)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:453)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addClassFile(BcelWeaver.java:456)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addClassFile(BcelWeaver.java:480)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.initBcelWorld(AjBuildManager.java:904)
    at 
    ... (shortened)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad WeaverState.Kind: -115.  File was :<Unknown>::0
    at org.aspectj.weaver.WeaverStateInfo.read(WeaverStateInfo.java:171)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.AjAttribute.read(AjAttribute.java:105)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.Utility.readAjAttributes(Utility.java:101)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureAspectJAttributesUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:383)
    ... 131 more
 FAILED
```

The mentioned file is an abstract aspect, which is implemented in the webapp. So:

```
public abstract aspect AbstractClassInCore {
  @Before
  public void beforeMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {}
}
```

and

```
public aspect ImplClassInWebApp extends AbstractClassInCore {}
```

Build script core project (shortened):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.aspectj:gradle-aspectj:0.1.6"
  }
  project.ext {
    aspectjVersion = '1.8.13'
  }
}

apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: "aspectj.gradle"

compileJava {  options.encoding = "UTF-8"  }

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

// to move some resources to correct location
jar {
  from ('./src/main/java') {
    include 'META-INF/resources/**/*.*'
  }
}

dependencies {
  // ... other dependencies
  // AspectJ
  compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.13'
}
```

Build script webapp project (shortened):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.aspectj:gradle-aspectj:0.1.6"
  }
  project.ext {
    aspectjVersion = '1.8.13'
  }
}

apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "aspectj.gradle"

compileJava {  options.encoding = "UTF-8"  }

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile project(':core')
  compile project(':other-subproject') // has no aspects
}
```

I have searched for the two key exceptions. As far as I see it, they occur when one attempts to weave an already woven class again. Therefore I conclude that the cause lies in the multiproject setup and should be fixed in the Gradle build scripts. I have tried several modifications, but the situation did not change. For example removing the plugin from either script did not make difference to the war task. However, it would make a difference in the final class, which will miss the aspect.

The refresh gradle action and the deployment of the webapp on the WildFly server are working normally. This indicates that what I want should work, but apparently the two processes do not behave the same. Eclipse is also still able to export a .war, but this won't work for continous integration and is less convenient.

Comment: Hi there. I cannot help you with Gradle, but just in case you consider using Maven instead, let me know.

Comment: @kriegaex Hi, changing to Maven is not an option, but maybe i can extrapolate a solution for Maven to Gradle. Because the first exception is fired from [ant:iajc], which might be what Maven (or a rather a plugin) is using as well.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but that's not my kind of game and too vague for me to put my sparetime into it. Good luck though!